# CSS isn't being applied to _app.js - NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, next.js

I have a stylesheet with tailwind styles and it isn't being applied to the `_app.js` module

https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-franklin-f3slz?file=/styles.css

All the steps in order to install Tailwind were followed.

What is the reason for that behavior?

Comment: The error says there's an issue with the `build-manifest.json` file. Looks like this guy on github had the same issue. https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/10586

Comment: Consider using tailwindcss v1.4+ which comes with built-in PurgeCSS. Here is a [working example](https://github.com/hangindev/next-tailwind-demo) you may follow. Check out `tailwind.config.js` and `postcss.config.js`.